# What jQuery IDE is this guy using?

Tags: jquery, macos, ide

In this video: http://vimeo.com/116991

I want to know because the result is changing as he codes it, and I want to use the IDE which has that feature.

Comment: Ya, def is TextMate.. and "that guy" is John Resig, the creator of jQuery. :)

Comment: Not TextMate... see my answer below. I'm gonna have to try this new-to-me editor out as well.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. Very cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, it's [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/)

See here: http://ejohn.org/blog/etherpad-real-time-editing-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Correction: It's not [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), but there is a preference to "Save files when focus is lost".

Answer (score 0):

Aptana studio has intellisense for jQuery and there is also plugin for dream viewer